# Extending a non-static class nested in non-baseclass implementing an interface

Tags: java

First, an idealized working example of doing almost what I want to do:

```
public final class One {
    private int i;

    public class InOne {
        public int foo() { return i; }
    }
}

public class Two {
    private final One aOne = new One();

    Object getInTwo() {
        return aOne.new InOne() {
            public int someMethod() { return foo() + 100; }
        };
    }
}
```

Fine, I can extend a non-static class in a non-baseclass, by qualifying new with an enclosing instance. But of course, as it stands this makes no sense, since `someMethod` becomes inaccessible in the returned object. In actuality, the return type of `getInTwo` is not supposed to be `Object` but `SomeInterface`, defined like this:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    int someMethod();
}
```

As far as I know, there is no way to create an anonymous class that both extends a class and implements an interface not implemented by that class. So I'll have to do a non-anonymous class, something like this:

```
public class Two {
    private final One aOne = new One();

    Object getInTwo() {
        class InTwo extends One.InOne implements SomeInterface {
            public int someMethod() { return foo() + 100; }
        }
        return new InTwo();
    }
}
```

Now the compiler tells me that an enclosing instance that contains `One.InOne` is required, which makes sense, but I *have* the object that I want to be the enclosing instance, and in the anonymous class case I was able to specify that by `aOne.new`. But now that I can't use an anonymous class, I can't specify the enclosing instance, or can I?

Obviously there are ways around this by moving things around in the class hierarchy (e.g., encapsulating an InOne in the InTwo instead if extending), which look fine in this idealized toy example, but in the context I actually want to do this they get much messier, so what I am asking is actually what I would like to do. As far as I can see, there is nothing structural that prevents it, it's just a syntax problem.

Comment: Should `One` be `final` class?

Comment: Yes, that's an actual complication: it prevents me from extending InOne inside something that extends One.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
public class Two {
   private final One aOne = new One();

   Object getInTwo() {
      class InTwo extends One.InOne implements SomeInterface {

            public InTwo(){
                aOne.super();
            }
            public int someMethod() { return foo() + 100; }
       }
       return new InTwo();
    }
}
```

Your problem is that the inner class of `One.InOne` can only exist within the context of an *instance* of `One`. Therefore, in the constructor, you must be able to provide an enclosing instance of any class than extends `One.InOne`.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** very beautiful, and I wouldn't recommend it at all... anyway - here you go:

```
public class Two {
    private final One aOne = new One();

    Object getInTwo() {
        class InTwo extends One.InOne implements SomeInterface {
            public InTwo() {
                Two.this.aOne.super();
            }
            public int someMethod() { return foo() + 100; }
        }
        return new InTwo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, well in my case the options are even less beautiful, and writing the super call without the `Two.this.` like @jacobhyphenated did also makes it a tiny bit less ugly.

Comment: Yes, a tiny bit - I actually added `Two.this.` to make it a tiny bit more ugly. ;)